# Why this @Override is incorrect?

Tags: java, enums, overriding

I want to implement the following interface from Apache Commons BeanUtils:

```
public interface Converter {
    // Convert the specified input object into an output object of the specified type
    <T>  T convert(java.lang.Class<T> tClass, java.lang.Object o);
}
```

My implementation should take a subclass of Enum and convert String object to an enum of the specified type. I attempted to use the following declaration:

```
class EnumConverter implements Converter {
    @Override
    public Enum convert(Class<Enum> tClass, Object o) {
        ...
    }
}
```

but compiler do not agree with me. It outputs:

> error: EnumConverter is not abstract and does not override abstract
>   method convert(Class,Object) in Converter
>
> error: name clash:
>   convert(Class,Object) in EnumConverter and
>   convert(Class,Object) in Converter have the same erasure, yet
>   neither overrides the other
>
> error: method does not override or
>   implement a method from a supertype

What is wrong with my implementation?

UPD. Please read the question more carefully. I cannot change Converter interface it is in Apache Commons BeanUtils library.

Comment: You need to make your interface generic as well.

Comment: @DaveNewton "I want to implement the following interface from Apache Commons BeanUtils". It a third-party library I cannot change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `convert` method in `EnumConverter` is not generic like the `convert` method in `Converter` is generic.  If the method to implement defines its own type parameter, then the overriding method must do so too.

However, it looks like you need the generic type parameter to be an `Enum`.  If so, then the interface `Converter` must be generic, not the method.  The `convert` method will refer to its interface's generic type parameter instead of defining its own.

```
interface Converter<T> {
    // Convert the specified input object into an output object of the specified type
    T convert(java.lang.Class<T> tClass, java.lang.Object o);
}
```

Then you can specify `Enum` when implementing the interface.

```
class EnumConverter implements Converter<Enum>{
    @Override
    public Enum convert(Class<Enum> tClass, Object o) {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you can't change the interface, then you *must* implement a generic method with the same generic method.  You can't add any bounds, such as `<T extends Enum<T>>`.

```
class EnumConverter implements Converter{
    @Override
    public <T> T convert(Class<T> tClass, Object o) {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you want it to work with only enums, then you'll have to enforce it at runtime:

```
if (!Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(tClass))
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Class must specify an Enum!");
```

Comment: Could you please write the correct class definition for my case (without changing Converter interface)?

Comment: I cannot change Converter interface.